# Ruby: Appending hashes to an array in an each loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of arrays called intervals.  I wish to build an array of hashes out of it, adding two key/value pairs to each hash (start_ts and stop_ts).

```
require 'date'
date = '2014-06-12'
totalhash = Hash.new
totalarray = Array.new
payload2 = Array.new
totals = Array.new

intervals = [["Current", 0, 9999],
             ["1 to 4", -4, -1],
             ["5 to 15", -15, -5],
             ["16 to 30", -30, -16],
             ["31 to 60", -60, -31],
             ["61 to 90", -90, -61],
             ["91+", -9999, -91]]

intervals.each do |int|
    label, start, stop = int
    # Parse date and then convert to UNIX epoch (.to_time.to_i chain)
    start_ts = (Date.parse("#{date}") + start).to_time.to_i
    stop_ts = (Date.parse("#{date}") + stop).to_time.to_i

    totalhash[:label]             = label
    totalhash[:start]             = start
    totalhash[:stop]              = stop
    totalhash[:start_ts]          = start_ts
    totalhash[:stop_ts]           = stop_ts

    totalarray << totalhash
    totals = totalarray.reduce Hash.new, :merge
    puts totals
    puts 'totals size: ' + totals.size.to_s
end
```

The end result should be an array of seven hashes.  Currently the array totalarray seems to be overwritten on each pass as opposed to being appended to.

What am I doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: How you ran this code? It has too many syntax error..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I only see one syntax error: `intervals.each do |int| do` (`do` twice).

Comment: I added require 'date' and removed the offending second do. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jordan If you run, you will get another one, with OP's previous code. But after that, I didn't run it..

Comment: Can you explain what `totals` is intended to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want a 1-for-1 output from an array, use `map`. It reduces the need for all those intermediate variables.

```
# Parse date outside the loop as per @Uri's comment
day = Date.parse(date)

t = intervals.map do |interval|
      label, start, stop = interval
      {
        label:    label,
        start:    start,
        stop:     stop,
        start_ts: (day + start).to_time.to_i,
        stop_ts:  (day + stop).to_time.to_i
      }
    end
```

This results in your desired seven-hash array.

As for the single hash output you are getting: your `reduce` line is the culprit. I'm not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: These are all good answers but I'm accepting this as it was clearest to me.  Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Good point @UriAgassi, I've incorporated your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
totalarray << totalhash
```

does not copy `totalhash`, it merely appends a reference to the end of `totalarray`. It would make a lot more sense to say:

```
totalarray << {
  # build the Hash inline right here
}
```

Your code ends up with `intervals.length` references to exactly the same Hash in `totalarray`. Then your `reduce` merges that Hash into itself and that does nothing useful. Actually your `totals = totalarray.reduce Hash.new, :merge` does nothing useful even if `totalarray` is properly built, you could just say `totals = totalarray.last` and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this sort of thing this way:

```
myArray = [['cow','moo'],['dog','woof'],['duck','quack'],['fox','?']]

myArray.collect! do |animal|
    animal = {animal[0]=>animal[1]}
end

puts myArray.inspect
```

I am not familiar enough with `reduce` or `inject`to comment on your use here. But here is an edited version of your original code that I think does what you want:

```
require 'date'
date = '2014-06-12'
#totalhash = Hash.new
totalarray = Array.new
payload2 = Array.new
totals = Array.new

intervals = [["Current", 0, 9999],
         ["1 to 4", -4, -1],
         ["5 to 15", -15, -5],
         ["16 to 30", -30, -16],
         ["31 to 60", -60, -31],
         ["61 to 90", -90, -61],
         ["91+", -9999, -91]]

intervals.each do |int|
    totalhash = Hash.new   #moved your hash creation here, in the iteration
    label, start, stop = int
    # Parse date and then convert to UNIX epoch (.to_time.to_i chain)
    start_ts = (Date.parse("#{date}") + start).to_time.to_i
    stop_ts = (Date.parse("#{date}") + stop).to_time.to_i

    totalhash[:label]             = label
    totalhash[:start]             = start
    totalhash[:stop]              = stop
    totalhash[:start_ts]          = start_ts
    totalhash[:stop_ts]           = stop_ts

    totalarray << totalhash
    #totals = totalarray.reduce Hash.new, :merge
    #puts totals
    #puts 'totals size: ' + totals.size.to_s
end

puts totalarray.inspect #see the array object as is using 'inspect'
```

~

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider changing your data structure.  I don't think it's wise to include the computed times since the epoch in each hash; rather, just compute those values as needed with a helper method:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.parse('2014-06-12')
  #=> #<Date: 2014-06-12 ((2456821j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

def start_stop_to_time(d, date)
  (date + d).to_time.to_i
end
```

For example,

```
start_stop_to_time(-4, date) #=> 1402210800
```

`total_array` would then be:

```
total_array = [[:label, :start, :stop]].product(intervals)
                                       .map { |k,v| k.zip(v).to_h }
  #=> [{:label=> "Current", :start=>    0, :stop=>9999},
  #    {:label=>  "1 to 4", :start=>   -4, :stop=>  -1},
  #    {:label=> "5 to 15", :start=>  -15, :stop=>  -5},
  #    {:label=>"16 to 30", :start=>  -30, :stop=> -16},
  #    {:label=>"31 to 60", :start=>  -60, :stop=> -31},
  #    {:label=>"61 to 90", :start=>  -90, :stop=> -61},
  #    {:label=>     "91+", :start=>-9999, :stop=> -91}]
```

I do not understand the purpose of `totals`, so I cannot comment on that.